# Cannot get label.text c#

Tags: c#, event-handling, label, addition, creation

I am new in C#, and now I have a problem that I cannot solve.

I have created the same label on multiple tabpages:

```
    public Label ChosenType = new Label();

    private void EvalType()
    {
        Label labelChosenType = new Label();
        labelChosenType.AutoSize = false;
        labelChosenType.Left = 710;
        labelChosenType.Top = 3;
        labelChosenType.Width = 350;
        labelChosenType.Height = 96;
        labelChosenType.Text = "Some text";
        labelChosenType.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
        labelChosenType.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        labelChosenType.BackColor = Color.Red;
        labelChosenType.ForeColor = Color.White;
        labelChosenType.Click += new EventHandler(labelChosenType_Click);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(labelChosenType);
    }

   private void SetGeneralInfo()
    {           
        for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectTab(i);
            EvalType();
        }
    }

    private void labelChosenType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(labelChosenType.Text);
    }
```

The problem is that the messagebox is blank. Why can't I get the text from label? (This is not the main function, but this is simpliest way, to show the problem)

I have tried to add name like= "some text" + i, but it was the same on all tabs, and it didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: the message box appears, but it is blank

Comment: seems like the label object's instantiation is limited to the void method only, you need to put it `outside` the void method

Comment: In the `labelChoosenType_Click()` method, to what does the `labelChoosenType` identifier refer? It definitely doesn't refer to the **local** variable `labelChoosenType` declared in the `EvalType()` method. Do you ever set it to something useful? Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Oh, and the word is spelled "chosen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing more code... my best guess is that the `labelChoosenType` you are referring to in the `labelChooseType_Click()` event handler is not the `Label` you think it is.

Each new `Label` you add to the `TabControl` is a `new Label` - and **not** the Label referred to by `labelChoosenType` outside of the `EvalType()` method. So when you click on the `Label`, the `text` property refers to another object that you have not initialized using the `EvalType()` method.

If you're trying to act on multiple objects of the same type in a single event handler, you're much better off using the `object sender` parameter. As it stands, it is totally unclear what object `labelChoosenType` refers to.

```
private void labelChoosenType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;
    if (clickedLabel != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(clickedLabel.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        // clickedLabel is not a Label or is null, do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to declare the Label Object Public/Private (it needs to be outside the void function) as of your current structure, the Label Object is only accessible in the `void EvalType()` Function

```
public Label labelChoosenType = new Label();

private void EvalType()
{
    labelChoosenType.AutoSize = false;
    labelChoosenType.Left = 710;
    labelChoosenType.Top = 3;
    labelChoosenType.Width = 350;
    labelChoosenType.Height = 96;
    labelChoosenType.Text = "Some text";
    labelChoosenType.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
    labelChoosenType.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    labelChoosenType.BackColor = Color.Red;
    labelChoosenType.ForeColor = Color.White;
    labelChoosenType.Click += new EventHandler(labelChoosenType_Click);
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(labelChoosenType);
}

private void labelChoosenType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(labelChoosenType.Text);
}
```

try and check if this would work.

Comment: I have declared it before the question, just didn't mention it - sorry for that and the misspelling

Comment: *the Label object is only accessible in the void EvalType() function* - this is not true. The reference to it will also be added to the `TabControl` object and carried into the click event handler as `object sender`.